# Best practice for updating Rails database to stop getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

General question here about Rails development. If say I develop a Rails application and then down the line I add in a column to a table in my database (example I add in new product description ability for a product), what is the best way to go about this so that when I navigate to a products page containing the new data I don't receive "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" for all the products that have already been created but now don't contain the information for the description data.

Any advice would be great. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options:

1. Use `default` while adding column.

   ```
   add_column :table, :column_name, :string, default: 'some_default'
   ```
2. Use safe navigation

   ```
   some_object&.column_name      # With Ruby 2.3+
   some_object.try(:column_name) # No matter what Ruby version
   ```

Comment: Cool so most definitely will be best to include the default when adding a column to avoid nil errors. My worry is launching a website getting some users then updating the website and errors cropping up everywhere because of new columns being blank in parts of the site. Thanks Andrey